# Simple equation involving complex norm

Tags: complex-analysis

So I've just started complex analysis and was given the following problem:

$$|e^{i\theta}-1|=2$$

One only need recall Euler's identity to know that the solution is $\theta=\pi$. However, I was supposed to verify my solution geometrically and had a question.

The LHS of the norm is simply the unit circle in the complex plane. Since the angle $\pi$ provides a unit vector pointing toward $-x$, I assumed that the unit circle had a phase shift of $1$ unit to the left, meaning the sum of two unit vectors pointing left from the origin would have distance $2$ from the origin, thus satisfying the equation.

However, I believe my professor said that the circle was centred at $(1,0)$--not $(-1,0)$--and I just don't see how the problem works if this is true.

Could someone clear things up a bit?

Comment: Consider the intersection of a circle center at $0$ with radius $2$ and another circle center at $-1$ with radius $1$.

Comment: Nice, I like how this and the top answer treat the centres of each circle differently and arrive at the same result.

In $\Bbb R^2$, $(x-1)$ is a phase shift to the right. Is this the opposite case in complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrically, $\,|z-1|=2\,$ is the locus of points at distance $\,2\,$ from fixed point $\,+1\,$ i.e. the circle of radius $\,2\,$ centered at $\,1\,$, call it $\,\Gamma\,$.

On the other hand, $\,z = e^{i \theta} \mid \theta \in \mathbb{R}\,$ is the unit circle, which is internally tangent to $\,\Gamma\,$ at point $\,z=-1\,$, which is the only common point between the two circles.

Therefore, the unique solution is $\,z=-1\,$, which corresponds to $\,\theta = \pi\,$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$\mid e^{i\theta}-1\mid=2\Rightarrow (\cos\theta-1)^2+\sin^2\theta=4\Rightarrow -2\cos\theta=2\Rightarrow \cos\theta=-1\Rightarrow \theta\in\{(2n+1)\pi:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Hence $\mid e^{i\theta}-1\mid=2$ do ot represent a circle at all. But $\mid re^{i\theta}-1\mid=2$ does, where $r>0$.

After your comment:

In general $\mid re^{i\theta}-c\mid=r$ represents a circle centered at $c\in\mathbb{C}$. Here you have $\mid re^{i\theta}-c\mid=s$, where $r\neq s$. So this will not represent a circle. In particular in your case $r=1, s=2$.

Also $\mid re^{i\theta}-c\mid=\mid se^{i\theta}-d\mid$. For fixed $r,s,c,d$ you will get for which value of $\theta$ for which the those two circles intersect or touch. In your case $r=1,c=0,s=2,d=1$. So got $(-1,0)$, where those two circle touch.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a unit circle where $r=1$?

And I follow your work, clears it up a bit

Comment: Okay, I think I see the miscommunication. You were saying the solution set isn't a circle. I was trying to imply that the LHS of the norm itself could be interpreted as a unit circle.

Comment: @LanierFreeman it is final!